# Breadcrumbs not showing proper path

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I have Drupal 7.2 installed, in my site there are menu items like Tech Docs, Doc Tree etc.
For example in Tech Docs I have number of nodes.

After going to Tech Docs page, the breadcrumb looks like

```
Home >> Tech Docs
```

After clicking on a node in Tech Docs, the breadcrumb appeared like

```
Home >> node title
```

instead, I need the full path.

> Home >> Tech Docs >> node title

How can I solve this? Any ideas???

Comment: is that "node title" node is a sub menu of "Tech Docs" ?

Comment: No, 'Tech Docs' is a content type and 'node title' is a node of that content type, not a submenu.

Comment: There are number of modules for the same. You can check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86204/how-can-i-add-path-breadcrumb-to-node-nid/86239#86239

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the [Menu Position Module](https://drupal.org/project/menu_position).

This module allows you to create a "rule" that says all of the nodes of type "whatever" go under this menu entry.

So, for your specific case, you would go to Structure > Menu Position Rules and add a new one. Give it a name and location in the menu and specify which content type you want (or pages, or users, or terms).

This is beneficial as it means you don't need to add each node to the menu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have set correct patterns for the content type by going to /admin/config/search/path/patterns
2. If the node is not in menu then you will have to either put it in menu or create a Taxonomy that reflects your Main menu and add that to your content type so when creating nodes you select what section they live in. Then you can adjust patterns to something like: [node:field-tag-section:parents:join-path]/[node:field-tag-section:name]/[node:title]
3. Use a module like Easy Breadcrumbs ( https://drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb ) which will give you more control over the breadcrumbs